# how to apply boxcox for multiple series in tsibble

Tags: r, tsibble

I would like to apply boxcox transformation for many series in tsibble data.
Can't figure how to do it.

```
require(fpp3)
require(fpp)
require(fable)
require(tsibble)
require(tsibbledata)
require(feasts)
require(ggplot2)
require(lubridate)

long = aus_production %>%
  select(Quarter, Beer, Bricks) %>%  
  gather(var, value, 2:3) %>% 
  as_tsibble()

lam = long %>%
  features(value, features = guerrero) 

long %>% 
  nest(-var) %>% 
  inner_join(lam) %>% 
  mutate(data_lambda = purrr::map(.x = data, ~box_cox(.x, lambda_guerrero)))
```

I tried many combinations, but failed.
Maybe there is simpler option.
This is simple example, with two series, but I can imagine, that I have 200 series, so I don't want to do it with hard coding.

Best
Sewe

Comment: What is `long_train`?  Please show all the packages used

Comment: @akrun I add all changes you asked for

Comment: The answer in this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630580/given-a-tsibble-with-more-than-one-key-is-tidyverts-able-to-box-cox-each-time